# python algorithm to be done in a pythonic fashion?

Tags: python, algorithm

Given an input text array

```
input_array = [
    'JUNK', 'Mon', 'JUNK', '10am', 'JUNK', '-', ' 5pm',
    '6pm', '-', '9pm', 'JUNK', 'Tue', '10am', '-', 'JUNK', '5pm'
]
```

should be converted to a JSON

```
[
  {
    "weekday_name": "monday",
    "starting_time": "10am",
    "ending_time": "5pm"
  },
  {
    "weekday_name": "monday",
    "starting_time": "6pm",
    "ending_time": "10pm"
  },
  ...
]
```

Although this is a simple algorithm, I'm forced to create temporary variables which is usually considered **non-pythonic**.

The code with ugly temporary variables

```
import pprint

input_array = ['JUNK','Mon','JUNK','10am','JUNK','-','5pm','6pm','-','9pm','JUNK','Tue','10am','-','JUNK','5pm']

business_hours = []
start_hours = None
end_hours = None
current_day = None
dash_found = False

days_of_the_week = {}
days_of_the_week['Mon'] = 'monday'
days_of_the_week['Tue'] = 'tuesday'
days_of_the_week['Wed'] = 'wednesday'
days_of_the_week['Thu'] = 'thursday'
days_of_the_week['Fri'] = 'friday'
days_of_the_week['Sat'] = 'saturday'
days_of_the_week['Sun'] = 'sunday'

for x in input_array:
    if x in days_of_the_week:
        current_day = days_of_the_week[x]     
    elif x[0].isdigit() and dash_found == False:
        starting_time = x        
    elif x == '-':
        dash_found = True    
    elif x[0].isdigit() and dash_found == True:
        ending_time = x
        business_hours.append({"weekday_name":current_day,"starting_time":starting_time,"ending_time":ending_time})
        dash_found = False


pprint.pprint(business_hours)
```

Can i make my code less ugly and accomplish the same without having to create many temporary variables in python?

Comment: are the positions set? So input_array[1] is always a day? or does 'Junk' stand for any number of items you don't want?

Comment: Is it normal that your array is missing a day for `6pm-9pm`?

Comment: @Holt That means it should be included in the same day. (same day but two working hours)

Comment: @Kameegaming In this case 'Junk' is just the string 'JUNK' and input_array[1] can be anything. the days and time occur in proper format in the array but they can have any number of 'JUNK' variables between them eg. ["mon",'JUNK',10am,'-','JUNK','JUNK','6pm','JUNK' ... etc ]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your data are always in the same order:

```
# Here you remove all the cells in your array which are not a day of the week
# or a time (not the call to "list" before filter object are not indexable in Python 3+)
data = list(filter(lambda x: x in days_of_the_week or x[0].isdigit(), input_array))
while data:
    # Get the first item available and remove it
    curday = days_of_the_week[data.pop(0)]
    # For each couple (start, end), add an item to business_hours
    while data and data[0][0].isdigit():
        business_hours.append({
            'weekday_name':  curday,
            'starting_time': data[0],
            'ending_time':   data[1]
        })
        data = data[2:]
```

There are certainly plenty of way of doing this, you will probably be stuck with the `curday` variable since you have to memorize it (you could use the latest entry in `business_hours` but it would be uglier, IMO).

**Edit:** Someone suggested an edit saying `list` is not necessary. Since I don't know which version of python you are using, I assume `python 3.0`, in which case `list` is mandatory (`filter` are kind of `generator` in `python 3.0`, so they cannot be indexed). If you are using `python 2.0`, `list` may not be mandatory.

---

For the fun of it, here is a one liner using reduce (do I have to tell you not to do that?):

```
from functools import reduce # Okay, okay, 2 lines!
reduce (lambda r, x: r + [{'weekday_name': days_of_the_week[x]}] if x in days_of_the_week 
                     else r + [{'weekday_name': r[-1]['weekday_name'], 'starting_time': x}] if len(r[-1]) == 3 
                     else (r[-1].update({'starting_time': x}), r)[1] if len(r[-1]) == 1 
                     else (r[-1].update({'ending_time': x}), r)[1], 
        filter(lambda x: x in days_of_the_week or x[0].isdigit(), input_array), [])
```

Comment: One of the key aspect of writing a code the script to be transparent for later reviews. That's  why we should avoid of usage of lambda and some virtually "tricky" solution if possible. I love the way you do it and eventually I use these shortcuts too, - and I enjoy it :) -but you should aware of the other aspects too.

Comment: @GyörgySolymosi I understand your point of view, but I don't think it applies here: The first line (with the lambda) is easily understandable (you are filtering under a specific condition), the 2 loops maybe needs one comment but nothing complicated here as soon as you know on which data structure you are working and python slicing (which I consider a requirement for any python user). And (of course), the later example using `reduce` was pure `joke`. Anyway, this is my own opinion, and this is a long debate subject ;)

Answer (score 0):

The following script is fairly forgiving in terms of the input, as such I cannot see a way around a couple of variables.

I have added another test case for Sunday with 3 opening times and some differently placed JUNK.

```
import pprint

input_array = [
    'JUNK', 'Mon', 'JUNK', '10am', 'JUNK', '-', ' 5pm',
    '6pm', '-', '9pm', 'JUNK', 'Tue', '10am', '-', 'JUNK', '5pm',
    "Sun  ", " 8am", "-  ", "JUNK", "MORE JUNK", " 9pm", "10am  ", "-", " 1pm", " 6pm", "-", "8pm"]

days_of_the_week = {'mon' : 'monday', 'tue' : 'tuesday', 'wed' : 'wednesday',
    'thu' : 'thursday', 'fri' : 'friday', 'sat' : 'saturday', 'sun' : 'sunday'}

business_hours = []
start = None

for entry in input_array:
    entry = entry.strip().lower()
    if entry in days_of_the_week:
        current_day = days_of_the_week[entry]
    elif entry[0].isdigit() and start:
        business_hours.append({"weekday_name": current_day, "starting_time": start, "ending_time": entry})
        start = None
    elif entry[0].isdigit():
        start = entry

pprint.pprint(business_hours)
```

Giving the following output:

```
[{'ending_time': '5pm', 'starting_time': '10am', 'weekday_name': 'monday'},
 {'ending_time': '9pm', 'starting_time': '6pm', 'weekday_name': 'monday'},
 {'ending_time': '5pm', 'starting_time': '10am', 'weekday_name': 'tuesday'},
 {'ending_time': '9pm', 'starting_time': '8am', 'weekday_name': 'sunday'},
 {'ending_time': '1pm', 'starting_time': '10am', 'weekday_name': 'sunday'},
 {'ending_time': '8pm', 'starting_time': '6pm', 'weekday_name': 'sunday'}]
```